# Command in command in Redis

Tags: database, terminal, redis

I just started Redis. I need to create a database for online store or whatever. Main idea to show functionality. I never worked in Redis and terminal, so a bit confusing. Firstly I want to create a database of users with id users counter:

```
SET user:id 1000 
INCR user:id
(integer) 1001
```

Can I use somehow command in command like:

```
HMSET incr user:id username "Lacresha Renner" gender "female" email "renner@gmail.com" 
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for HMSET
```

in case that my database automatically count new users in database. Or it's not possible in Redis? Should I do it by hands, like user:1, user:2, user:n?
I am working in terminal (MacOS).

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of new users in the database or are you trying to generate a unique userId like you would with a sequence in a relational database?  Your code and comments suggest both options.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a unique user's sequence in a relational database. I think so. Should I do it manually or Redis can count them by itself?
Do not know(

Answer (score 3):

`HMSET` receives a key name, and pairs of elements names and values. 
Your first argument (`incr`) is invalid, and the `id` part of the second should be explicit id.

e.g.:

```
HMSET user:1000 username "Lacresha Renner" gender "female" email "renner@gmail.com"
```

Regarding your first `SET`, you should have one key that its whole purpose is a running uid, you should use the reply of `INCR` as the new UID for the new user HASH key name (1000 in the above example).

If you never delete users, the value of the running UID will be the number of users in your system. If you do delete users, you should also insert the UID into a SET and remove the UID once you delete the user. In that case, an `SCARD` should give you the number of users in your system, and `SMEMBERS` (or `SSCAN`) will give you all of their UIDs.

Comment: I think I got it! at least! Thx! 
But what about HLEN? I think it could show me how many users I have in database now. Right?

Comment: If moving makes you more active here, I'll upvote it ;)

Comment: @Pon4a, HLEN will give you the number of elements in a hash, in the example it will be 3 (for username, gender and email).

Comment: I created database where 10 ppl like:
[SET user:0:username "Lacresha Renner"]
then 5 items list:
[hmset item:1 category "smartphone" model "Apple iPhone" price 600]
BUT i don't know how to create a basket(card). How to make this relationship? LOGIC should be like: 
[item:1:basket = user:0:username]